# Changing an Entity creates a new one as well

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ado.net

I am making a ASP.NET app which uses ADO.NET.

The user can create records and change them as well, but when i change the record, then it is changed as it should, but it creates a new identical record(with a different key) as well.

When a user want to change a record, he selects it from a list (entire entities are taken) and gets to a new page, and then the textBoxes are filled with info from the entity:
NOTE: KorisnickaSesija.izabraniProjekt is the record (the whole entity) i want to change

```
if (KorisnickaSesija.izabraniProjekt != null)
{
    txtName.Text = KorisnickaSesija.izabraniProjekt.naziv;
    txtOpis.Text = KorisnickaSesija.izabraniProjekt.opis;
    txtPlaca.Text = KorisnickaSesija.izabraniProjekt.cijenaPoSatu.ToString();
    txtGodina.Text = KorisnickaSesija.izabraniProjekt.deadline.Value.Year.ToString();
    txtMjesec.Text = KorisnickaSesija.izabraniProjekt.deadline.Value.Month.ToString();
    txtDan.Text = KorisnickaSesija.izabraniProjekt.deadline.Value.Day.ToString();

    izabraneKategorije = KorisnickaSesija.izabraniProjekt.Kategorija.ToList();
    foreach (var item in izabraneKategorije)
    {
        sveKategorije.Remove(item);
    }
}
lbSveKategorije.DataSource = sveKategorije;
lbSveKategorije.DataTextField = "naziv";
lbSveKategorije.DataBind();
lbIzabraneKategorije.DataSource = izabraneKategorije;
lbIzabraneKategorije.DataTextField = "naziv";
lbIzabraneKategorije.DataBind();
```

after the user changed what he wants to change, i do this:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtName.Text.Length > 0 && txtOpis.Text.Length > 0 && txtPlaca.Text.Length > 0 && txtDan.Text.Length > 0 && txtMjesec.Text.Length > 0 && txtGodina.Text.Length > 0 && izabraneKategorije.Count > 0)
    {
            Projekt projekt = new Projekt();
            DateTime deadline = new DateTime(int.Parse(txtGodina.Text), int.Parse(txtMjesec.Text), int.Parse(txtDan.Text));
            projekt.naziv = txtName.Text;
            projekt.opis = txtOpis.Text;
            projekt.cijenaPoSatu = int.Parse(txtPlaca.Text);
            projekt.deadline = deadline;
            projekt.datumObjavljivanja = DateTime.Now;
            foreach (var item in izabraneKategorije)
            {
                projekt.Kategorija.Add(item);
            }

            projekt.Korisnik = KorisnickaSesija.logiraniKorisnik;

            if (KorisnickaSesija.izabraniProjekt != null)
            {
                projekt.projektID = KorisnickaSesija.izabraniProjekt.projektID;
                ProjektService.izmjeniProjekt(projekt);   //change record
            }
            else
            {
                ProjektService.dodajProjekt(projekt);  //create new record - dosnt go here by accident, i checked
            }

        Response.Redirect("HomeEmployer.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        //ispisi da je greska
    }
}
```

ProjektService.izmjeniProjekt(projekt); is this:

```
public static void izmjeniProjekt(Projekt k)
{
    Projekt kk = getProjektByID(k.projektID);
    kk.naziv = k.naziv;
    kk.opis = k.opis;
    kk.cijenaPoSatu = k.cijenaPoSatu;
    kk.deadline = k.deadline;
    kk.Kategorija.Clear();
    foreach (var item in k.Kategorija)
    {
        kk.Kategorija.Add(item);
    }
    Context.context.SaveChanges();

}
```

getProjektByID(k.projektID); is this:

```
public static Projekt getProjektByID(int id)
{
    var query = (from k in Context.context.Projekt
                 where id == k.projektID

                 select k).FirstOrDefault();
    return query;
}
```

**EDIT**

After reaserching a bit i think that the issue might be with the fact that "Projekt" has a many-to-many relationship with the entity "Kategorija" via a in-between table. That table is not visible in the model, instead "Projekt" has Projekt.Kategorija, and Kategorija has Kategorija.Projekt.
Also, i first made my database and after that generated my model out of it when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i could not edit mlh0's answer i will post a seperate one.

When adding an object into the database using ado.NET, and that object has relationships with other objects, then it is important to NOT USE THE NAVIGATIONAL PROPERTIES WHEN SAVING. Instead use secondary keys.

If you want to add a "City", then do

```
City object = new City();
object.name = "Some name";
object.countryID = someCountry.countryID;  //this will work as intended
//object.country = someCountry;  //this will work NOT as intended
yourContext.City.addObject(object);
yourContext.saveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this is entity framework issue,you may use "Context.context.Projekt.Find(id)" in your "izmjeniProjekt" instead of your function "getProjektByID",maybe passing and getting types with the functions is the problem, by the way your naming is awesome !

the problem is obvious, entity framework recognizes your "Projekt" as a new entry, so the problem is the Key of your database table, you probably used code first migrations to creating your database and you didn't specify the key, but by the way, you have the id, in my opinion its not necessary to get the "Projekt" from data context, just use it!

maybe what i'm trying to say is not clear so watch this video ( you will see your problem there ) to have a better understanding of entity framework.

[Julie Lerman Speaks](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Entity-Framework-Tips-and-Tricks)

Comment: Context.context.Projekt dosnt have a Find(int) function, im not sure what you mean.  Im Croatian and this is for by bacherlor work, so im using croatian names ^^

Comment: I tried `Projekt kk = Context.context.Projekt.Where(p => p.projektID == k.projektID).FirstOrDefault();` instead of ´getProjektByID ´ and its the same as before

Comment: Please elaborate responses with actual code snippets when possible. Helps better understand your response

Comment: First i think you could reuse some of the user's code with your addition or changes to illustrate your thoughts. Also you can place code snippet of your extract in <code></code> ( or select and click on the {} icon on top of post box )

Comment: I made my model using the option to generate it out of a existing database, does this help? And what do you mean by "you have the id, in my opinion its not necessary to get the "Projekt" from data context, just use it!"